# Does Tianocore's DUET allow more advanced options on "locked down" PCs?

Tags: bios, uefi

I'm considering attempting to install Tianocore's DUET on my old(er) Dell Precision T7400, that uses BIOS by default. If I do use DUET, would it allow for more advanced options such as changing core clock, fsb clock, and other options often seen on aftermarket motherboards but unavailable on most stock ones?

Comment: In the future, please be more specific. “T7400” is an ambiguous product name. One can deduce that you’re not referring to the Core 2 Duo T7400 CPU here, but it may not always be that clear.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for letting me know. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It doesn’t replace your BIOS but is a BIOS-booted UEFI emulation environment. As such, it doesn’t offer anything but booting operating systems in UEFI mode or running EFI applications.